# Can we put disable property to the angular selector

Tags: angular

I need to put disable property to the selector..But it's not working..Is there any other methods to achieve this??

```
<app-select [disabled]="select"></app-selcet>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You can disable certain fields only. If you are using a selector to display the layout and all. You cannot disable the div elements and text right. You can hide or show using *ngIf. If that is what the case you are trying. Otherwise you can handle using css to block the interaction from the user.

Comment: You want to disable the app-select component ?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? You need to put an `@Input() disabled;` inside the app-select component if you wish to pass it.

Comment: This app-select is nothing but dropdown component....When I will use this app-select, i will get dropdown.. So I need to disable that for some condition

Comment: You pass `[disabled]="select"` to the **AppSelectComponent**, there you take it via @Input and disable your `select`

Answer (score 0):

Actually You need to use ***ngIf** directive for hide and show the App selectors or any selectors.Disable property is used for disable the fields Only.

Comment: @user11759028 Did you tried this for adding your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In template give

```
<app-select [disabled]="disabled"></app-select>
```

In ts file you can declare a variable like this

```
disabled : boolean = true;
```

Later if you want you can enable like `this.disabled = false;`

Declare a variable to decide true or false to decide disabled or not.

In directive you can do this

```
export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() disabled: boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And in the template you can bind this value to the disabled event.

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Field Name</mat-label>
   <mat-select placeholder="Select anything" name="any" [(ngModel)]="any" [disabled]="disabled" required>
       <mat-option>--</mat-option>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let type of list" [value]="type">
           <span>{{type.name}}</span>
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: @user11759028 Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer..But this is not my requirement...I am having predefined dropdown which is <app-select>...and I need to disable that for some condition.

Comment: That is what it is. In your directive whatever field. You need to pass the disabled value and disable it by giving `[disabled]="disabled"`. It is not what exactly you need to paste everything. That is just an example to understand

Comment: And If you update the code in the question and be more specified, That would be more helpful for everyone to solve the problem or what you are missing in your code. Thanks